# How do I compare the length of a string to an integer within the same list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My assignment is to get a list from the user and print out the second largest item in said list.

The user should be able to enter strings or integers.

I'm having issues comparing the two as I get errors when using max().

Here is my code thus far:

```
list_input_amount = int(input('How many items are in your list?: '))

for amount in range(list_input_amount):
    list_input = input('Please enter your list item: ')
    if list_input.isnumeric():
        random_list.append(int(list_input))
    else:
        random_list.append(list_input)

print(random_list)


def second_largest():
    maximum_list = set(random_list)
    maximum_list.remove(max(maximum_list))

    print(max(maximum_list))

second_largest()
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: And what is the problem ? you compare int by value and string by length ?

Comment: And how does the user enter the values? One by one, or all at once splitted with space

Comment: instead of `random_list.append(list_input)`, you could `append(len(list_input))` to append the string length. you second largest entry would then be `sorted(set(random_list))[-2]` - given that there are at least two inputs.

Comment: They enter the values 1 by 1 and at the end I need it to print whichever is longer so if the string is longer I need the string to be printed, if the number is bigger than a string is long I need the number to be printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can a dict `{}` to store the value that'll be used to compare, and then sort and take the second one.

Here is the code, a bit more generic to get the `nth` element :

```
# List comprehension
def nth_largest(values: {}, nth=0):
    return [k for k,v in sorted(values.items(), key=lambda kv:kv[1], reverse=True)][nth][0]

# Two steps
def nth_largest(values: {}, nth=0):
    sorted_x = sorted(values.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)
    return list(sorted_x)[nth][0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_input_amount = int(input('How many items are in your list?: '))
    dico_values = {}
    for amount in range(list_input_amount):
        list_input = input('Please enter your list item: ')
        if list_input.isnumeric():
            dico_values[int(list_input)] = int(list_input)
        else:
            dico_values[list_input] = len(list_input)
    print(nth_largest(dico_values, 1))
```

Comment: This seems to have worked perfectly for what I need. I need to deconstruct it to understand exactly how it works because a lot of this I still haven't really gotten into yet but it gives me something new to look at and learn and for that I thank you!